# "Transpose/Zip" function not working as expected

Tags: lua

I am trying to build an elegant transpose function using functions mapn and zip in Lua.

The mapn and zip are as follows (From the lua book):

```
function map(func, array)
 local new_array = {}
 for i,v in ipairs(array) do
   new_array[i] = func(v)
 end
 return new_array
end


function mapn(func, ...)
 local new_array = {}
 local i=1
 local arg_length = table.getn(arg)
 while true do
   local arg_list = map(function(arr) return arr[i] end, arg)
   if table.getn(arg_list) < arg_length then return new_array end
   new_array[i] = func(unpack(arg_list))
   i = i+1
 end
end
```

These work as expected.

I then define zip and transpose as:

```
function zip(...)
  return mapn(function(...) return {...} end,...)
end

function transpose(...)
  return zip(unpack(...))
end
```

Now transpose({{1,2},{3,4},{5,6}}) produces {{1,3,5},{2,4,6}} as expected.

But transpose({{1,2},{3,4},{5}})   does not produce {{1,3,5},{2,4}}. It only produces one row.

How can I get it to produce the result I wish for?

---

I just decided to write an "inelegant" function instead. It seems there's no smooth way to use mapn and friends.

```
function transp(L)
  local n=#L


  local m,M=1e42,0
  --Get the beginning and end of resultant transpose list.
  for i=1,n do
    for k,v in pairs(L[i]) do
      if M<k then M=k end
      if m>k then m=k end
    end
  end

  local nt={}
  for i=m,M do
    local rt={}
    for j=1,n do
      rt[j]=L[j][i]
    end
    table.insert(nt,rt)
  end
  return nt
end
```

Please critique and improve this candidate solution.

Comment: Your code contains some Lua 5.0 artifacts (namely `arg` and `table.getn`). If you're reading Programming in Lua, make sure that it is a second edition.

Comment: That `unpack(...)` looks highly suspicious to me. Make sure you understand what it does.

Comment: Are you sure that all the code in your post is correct? I've tested `transpose({{1,2},{3,4},{5,6}})` and `transpose({{1,2},{3,4},{5}})` and it returned `{{1},{2}}` in both cases. I'm using Lua 5.1, by the way.

Comment: @kikito I think he meant to use `mapn` inside `zip` instead of `map`.

Comment: The problem is `if table.getn(arg_list) < arg_length then return new_array end`. For the second time, `table.getn({2,4}) < table.getn({{1,2},{3,4},{5}})`, and so it returns before adding the `arg_list` to `new_array`. Leave it out, as in ponzao's answer and it should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed a few things in your code and I think it works now as intended, I've added comments inline.

```
function map(func, array)
  local new_array = {}
  for i, v in ipairs(array) do
    new_array[#new_array + 1] = func(v)
  end 
  return new_array
end

function mapn(func, ...)
  -- Variadic arguments bound to an array.
  local arrays = {...}
  local new_array = {}
  -- Simple for-loop.
  local i = 1 
  while true do
    local arg_list = map(function(arr) return arr[i] end, arrays)
    if #arg_list == 0 then
      break
    end 
    new_array[i] = func(unpack(arg_list))
    i = i + 1 
  end 
  return new_array
end


-- Using 'mapn' instead of 'map' (probably how you intended).
function zip(...)
  return mapn(function(...) return {...} end,...)
end

-- Same as before.
function transpose(...)
  return zip(unpack(...))
end
```

Usage example:

```
for _, row in pairs(transpose({{1,2},{3,4},{5}})) do
  for _, col in pairs(row) do io.write(col .. ' ') end
  io.write('\n')
end
-- Output: 1 3 5 
--         2 4
```

Comment: Your `map` and his `map` do the same thing, due to how `ipairs` works.

Comment: @ponzao: you win, I'd made a slight mistake.

Comment: @Robin True, will fix it, I don't know what I was thinking (haven't coded in Lua for a while).

Comment: Is your mapn loop supposed to go only as far as #arrays? This looks wrong in the simple case where there is only one list passed to mapn.

Comment: @JohnSmith You are correct, this is why one should always write tests. I will fix my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The `{5}` in your example is being ignored because of this line:

```
if table.getn(arg_list) < arg_length then return new_array end
```

What you may want to do instead is break out of the loop only when `arg_list` is empty.

This will then give the result you want provided that the rows are monotonically increasing in length.

For the more general case, when later rows may be shorter than earlier ones
(e.g. `{{1,2},{3,4,5},{6}}`), you will need to keep track of the row lengths to allow for holes.  This can be done by adding an optional argument (and extra return value) to `map` to indicate the maximum index `i` for which `func(array[i])` was evaluated:

```
function map(func, array, len)
 local new_array = {}
 len = len or #array
 for i=1,len do
   new_array[i] = func(array[i])
 end
 return new_array, len
end

function mapn(func, ...)
 local new_array = {}
 local i=1
 local arg_length = select('#', ...)
 local args = {...}
 while true do
   local arg_list, num_results = map(function(arr) return arr[i] end, args, arg_length)
   if not next(arg_list) then return new_array end
   new_array[i] = func(unpack(arg_list, 1, num_results))
   i = i+1
 end
end

function zip(...)
  return mapn(function(...) return {...} end,...)
end

function transpose(...)
  return zip(unpack(...))
end
```